# Need to filter remaining emails from a specific sender

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I have filters set in place for eBay to apply labels to sold, offers, ended listings, and other important topics. Is there a way to filter all other emails from eBay that do not fall into the above categories and label them other?

Answer (score 1):

You can *try* to create a filter that looks at the sender and do a negative match against the existing labels.

```
Has the words: from:ebay@ebay.com -label:ebay-sold -label:ebay-ended -label:ebay-offers
Apply label: ebay-other
```

Gmail will probably balk at using `label:` in a filter search value, but as long as your "other" filter comes *after* the others, it will probably work.

Your other option is to take the criteria from your other filters and build a new filter that excludes those criteria.

Answer (score -2):

In the search bar in Gmail, type in `from:<email address here> <keyword here>`. Be sure to leave a space between the email and the keyword.